# NextActivity onCreate() is skipped

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating a social app and the users can upload an image and then write a caption on the next screen right after. My problem is that the activity where the user creates the caption, gets completely skipped over and goes to the profile page. The image goes to the firebase storage but I can't write a caption.

```
07-10 15:23:21.150 30970-31309/tabian.com.hash E/ImageLoader: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@f488c6e]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@f488c6e]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

GalleryFragment.Java

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
galleryImage = view.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
directorySpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDirectory);
mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
directories = new ArrayList<>();
Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: Started.");

ImageView shareClose = view.findViewById(R.id.ivCloseShare);
shareClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Closing the gallery screen.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity());
    }
});

    TextView nextScreen = view.findViewById(R.id.tvNext);
    nextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Navigating to the final share screen.");

            if (isTaskRoot()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                GalleryFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.return_to_fragment), getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment));
                GalleryFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
                Objects.requireNonNull(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity());
            }
        }
    });
    init();

    return view;

}
```

NextActivity.Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
    mFirebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(NextActivity.this);
    mCaption = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caption) ;

    setupFirebaseAuth();

    ImageView backArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBackArrow);
    backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Closing the activity");
            finish();
        }
    });

    TextView share = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShare);
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Navigating to the final share screen.");
            //upload the image to firebase
            Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "Attempting to upload new photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String caption = mCaption.getText().toString();

            if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))){
                imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
                mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, imgUrl,null);
            }
            else if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap))){
                bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap));
                mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, null,bitmap);
            }

        }
    });

    setImage();
}
```

ProfileActivity.Java :

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ProfileFragment.OnGridImageSelectedListener ,
    ViewPostFragment.OnCommentThreadSelectedListener,
    ViewProfileFragment.OnGridImageSelectedListener{

private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";

@Override
public void onCommentThreadSelectedListener(Photo photo) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCommentThreadSelectedListener:  selected a comment thread");

    ViewCommentsFragment fragment = new ViewCommentsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(getString(R.string.photo), photo);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.view_comments_fragment));
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onGridImageSelected(Photo photo, int activityNumber) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onGridImageSelected: selected an image gridview: " + photo.toString());

    ViewPostFragment fragment = new ViewPostFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(getString(R.string.photo), photo);
    args.putInt(getString(R.string.activity_number), activityNumber);

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.view_post_fragment));
    transaction.commit();

}


private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 4;
private static final int NUM_GRID_COLUMNS = 3;

private Context mContext = ProfileActivity.this;

private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private ImageView profilePhoto;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

    init();


}
```

Comment: Please post NextActivity onCreate code

Comment: Are you saying isTaskRoot() always returns false?

Comment: @TimOMalley I think so . It just never goes to that scene

Comment: @SangeetSuresh I just posted it

Comment: @TimOMalley any other help ?

Comment: Where is the code to navigate to profile screen. Can you post that whole code.

Comment: @SangeetSuresh I just updated my code